# jQuery $(this) passing through functions

Tags: jquery

I have two functions.  The first function is a click event with the second function being called within the first function.  Is it possible to still use $(this)  in the second function? If not, is it possible to get $(this) another way?

ex:

```
$('#table').find('.button').click(function() {
   var results = someResult;
   getSomethingElse();
});
function getSomethingElse(){
   **$(this).find('#table').append(results);**
}
```

Comment: Pass `this` into `getSomethingElse()`. Ex: `getSomethingElse(this)`, `function getSomethingElse(that){`

Comment: either use `apply` or `call` to pass the context, or pass `this` as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to still use the `this` from the instance of the previous function, you would need to pass it into the second function.

```
$('#table').find('.button').click(function() {
   var results = someResult;
   getSomethingElse($(this));
});
function getSomethingElse(ele){
   ele.find('#table').append(results);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to simply use `$(this)` in the second function in the way you described, but you can still use it another way like so:

```
$('#table').find('.button').click(function() {
    var results = someResult;
    getSomethingElse($(this), results);
});

function getSomethingElse(that, results){
    that.find('#table').append(results);
}
```

You must pass in both `$(this)` and `results` to the second function. If you do not also pass in `results`, you will not be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for!